# python dictionaires keys and values

Tags: python, algorithm

If I have a dictionary like this:

```
dict = {'a': ['Menny','Adam'], 'b': ['Steff','Bentz', 'Arik'], 'c': ['Helen','Stephonich', 'Marry', 'Kenny', 'Mike', 'Pring']
```

and so on.

I want to do a function that counts how many values there's on a key.
For example:

`>>> func(d, a)`

`>>> 2`

`>>> func(d, c)`

`>>> 6`

I know I need to use d.values, sum(len(values)) or something like this, but I don't know how.
please help me.
Thanks.

It's for a big project I'm working on and I'm stuck.
Thanks again.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Fisrt I suggest that you should read some python tutorials, if your have a big project to write but still dont know the basic usage of python.

1. You should not use dict to refer a dictionary. `dict` is python's keyword. Just like you would not define a variable whose name is `int` in C.
2. If you just want to get the length of an **iterable object** just use **len**(). it returns an int object. And function **sum**() returns the sum of an iterable object. So you cannot use `sum(len(your_dict))`, it's like `sum`(4)` and would not return anything.
3. Your `dict.value` is not a legal function or sth. Use `dict.values()`, which returns a tuple that contains every value in key-value pair, similarly `dict.keys()` returns all keys as a tuple.

Answer (score 2):

```
mydict = {'a': [4,'Adam'], 'b': [3,'John', 4], 'c': [4,'Stephonich', 3, 8, 8, 34]}

def func(myDict, key):
    return len(myDict[key])

print func(mydict, "a")
print func(mydict, "b")
print func(mydict, "c")
```

**Output**

```
2
3
6
```

Comment: OK, thanks. and if I want to check if there's some valus that are common between 2 values what should I do?

Comment: @thefourtheye done. thanks again.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20017501/checking-valus-and-keys-in-python