# Checking values and keys in Python

Tags: python, algorithm

If I have a dictionary like this:

```
dict = {'a': ['Menny','Adam'], 'b': ['Steff','Bentz', 'Arik'], 'c': ['Menny','Stephonich', 'Marry', 'Kenny', 'Mike', 'Pring']
```

and so on.

If I want to check if there's some values that are common between 2 lists in their keys. what should I do?

For example,
in a and c there's "Menny"...

Comment: common between two *keys*, perhaps?

Comment: I've corrected the question.

Comment: if it's a real problem in production ,you should change the data strcture of model,although this can be solved

Answer (score 4):

I'd build an inverse index:

```
from collections import defaultdict

reverse = defaultdict(set)

for key, values in dct.items():
    for value in values:
        reverse[value].add(key)
```

Now you can find any value that is shared between keys:

```
for value, keys in reverse.items():
    if len(keys) > 1:
        print(value, keys)
```

Demo:

```
>>> from collections import defaultdict
>>> dct = {'a': ['Menny','Adam'], 'b': ['Steff','Bentz', 'Arik'], 'c': ['Menny','Stephonich', 'Marry', 'Kenny', 'Mike', 'Pring']}
>>> reverse = defaultdict(set)
>>> for key, values in dct.items():
...     for value in values:
...         reverse[value].add(key)
... 
>>> for value, keys in reverse.items():
...     if len(keys) > 1:
...         print(value, keys)
... 
Menny {'c', 'a'}
```

If you want to test two keys, use:

```
def check_keys(dct, key1, key2):
    return not set(dct[key1]).isdisjoint(dct[key2])
```

Demo:

```
>>> check_keys(dct, 'a', 'c')
True
>>> check_keys(dct, 'a', 'b')
False
```

or, returning the common values:

```
def values_intersection(dct, key1, key2):
    return set(dct[key1]).intersection(dct[key2])
```

Demo:

```
>>> values_intersection(dct, 'a', 'c')
{'Menny'}
>>> values_intersection(dct, 'a', 'b')
set()
```

Comment: Thanks but it's not what I mean (my mistake I wasn't clear). a function that has input like: func(d, the first key, the second key)

Comment: @user2969278: If you are doing this more than once, then use the index still.

Comment: look what I've done untill now:


 def mutual_func(d,v1,v2):


    for k1 in d[v1]:


        for k2 in d[v22]:
            

if k1 == k2:


now I want to count also how many mutual keys are in this example of dict dictionary then only one.

Comment: @user2969278: That is *terribly* inefficient. Use sets instead.

Comment: What do you mean by sets?

Comment: @user2969278: Added a sample function.

Comment: I'm sorry, could you write the code without sets and without isdisjoint or  intersection? I'm not looking after efficiency, that's not my issue

Comment: @user2969278: Why would I want to do that? Sets are the obvious and clearest way to do this. You could use a loop over *one* of the two lists and use `in` to test against the other list, but that's not nearly as compact or efficient.

Comment: @user2969278: And you need to specify any constraints you have *up front* in your question. As you can see from the various edits, and the fact that you have to ask me for changes, that your question was not clear enough from the start.

Comment: @user2969278: And if you are worried you won't be able to explain this code to your teacher, why did you ask for a solution on Stack Overflow in the first place? :-)

Comment: Indeed my friend, and I'm sorry about this. My english is broken so I've some difficulties to write clearly and to understand others.
Anyway, if you could just write me the option without sets or isdisjoint. just simple loops.

Comment: `for value in dct[key1]: if value in dct[key2]: return True`.

Comment: so it's almost like what I did. great. Now if I want to know how many common values there, what I need do? using count?

Comment: @user2969278: You got it. Just keep a counter; set it to `0`, then `count += 1` every time the `in` test is `True`.

Comment: ok, but where to put the "count += 1"?

Comment: Oh come on, do try to think along a little. Try stuff out. Python has a very good interactive interpreter. Where do you *think* it goes?

Comment: But I tried...
Maybe like this?
   `counter = 0
    for value in d[K1]:
        if value in d[K2]:
            count += 1
            return counter`

Comment: And what did that do?

Comment: @user2969278 You need to try it yourself, now. I think we've done enough to help you.

Answer (score 1):

```
def check(value, dictionary, keys):
    return all(value in dictionary[key] for key in keys)
```

Demo:

```
>>> def check(value, dictionary, keys):
        return all(value in dictionary[key] for key in keys)

>>> d= {'a': ['Menny','Adam'], 'b': ['Steff','Bentz', 'Arik'], 'c': ['Menny','Stephonich', 'Marry', 'Kenny', 'Mike', 'Pring']}
>>> check('Menny', d, ['a', 'b'])
False
>>> check('Menny', d, ['a', 'c'])
True
>>>
```

If you want to have the keys which shared the values:

```
def check(value, d):
    keys_found = []
    for k,v in d.items():
        if value in v:
            keys_found.append(k)
    return keys_found
```

Demo:

```
>>> def check(value, d):
    keys_found = []
    for k,v in d.items():
        if value in v:
            keys_found.append(k)
    return keys_found

>>> check('Menny', d)
['c', 'a']
```

Comment: This only works if you know the value that is shared up front.